# \newcommand with optional argument

Tags: macros

The idea is define a command as

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}{This is the official long name}
```

and I use it as `\mycommand` several times in the document. But sometimes I would like a short name, something like \mycommand[short name] where *short name* replace *This is the official long name*. Is this possible in a simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simpler than Peter Grill's, but using the same idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\definealtcommand}{mmm}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s}{\IfBooleanTF{##1}{#3}{#2}}%
}

\definealtcommand{\mycommand}{This is the official long name}{Short name}

\begin{document}

\mycommand\ (Long version)

\mycommand* (Short version)

\end{document}
```

Remember to add `{}` or `\` after `\mycommand` without the `*` if you want a space to appear in the output.

[image]

Comment: The `s` is for the starred version right?

Comment: @azetina Yes, and `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` returns true if the `*` is found; one needs `##1` because it's a definition inside a definition.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would do it. Use `\SetMyTitle{<sort title>}{<long title>}` to define *both* the long and short titles. Then using `\MyTitle` you get the long title and `\MyTitle*` you get the short title:

[image]

---

The other option is to define `\SetMyTitle{<long title>}` and access this via `\MyTitle`. If you wish to provide a short title you can provide the optional paramter `\MyTitle{<short title>}`.

### Code: `Recommended`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@MyLongTitle}{}
\newcommand*{\@MyShortTitle}{}
\newcommand*{\SetMyTitle}[2]{%
    \def\@MyLongTitle{#2}%
    \def\@MyShortTitle{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyTitle}{s}{%
    {\bfseries\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\@MyShortTitle}{\@MyLongTitle}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\SetMyTitle{ShortTitle}{This is the official long name}

Long title is: \MyTitle

Short title is: \MyTitle*

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `Alternate`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@MyTitle}{}
\newcommand*{\SetMyTitle}[1]{%
    \def\@MyTitle{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyTitle}{o}{%
    {\bfseries\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\@MyTitle}{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\SetMyTitle{This is the official long name}

Long title is: \MyTitle

Short title is: \MyTitle[Short Title]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you also have a solution without the use of `xparse`? Thanks

Comment: @pluton: I don't, but you could post a new question. Or copy the code from xparse.sty into your .tex file :-).

Answer (score 6):

Also the powerful package `acronym` can be used for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\newacro{my}[short name]{This is the official long name}

\begin{document}
``\acl{my}'' is the long version.

The short version is ``\acs{my}''.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, the package `acronym` has a lot of more features, see the package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

And one simple version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][This is the official long name]{#1}    

\begin{document}
    \mycommand

    \mycommand[Short name]
\end{document}
```